# Jquery mobile get json from .php file workes locally but not on server

Tags: php, jquery, json, jquery-mobile, getjson

i am working on a Jquery mobile project and want to load a json. The json comes from a .php file. The problem is that it will not load.

My .php file looks like this.

```
<?php
    $query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `data`");
    while($data=mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
    $output['result'] []=$data;
    header('Content-Type: application/json', true);
    echo json_encode($output);  
?>
```

I tried 2 different methods inside my jquery:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://www.example.com/jsonfile.php",
    dataType : "json"
}).success(function(data){

$.getJSON('http://www.example.com/jsonfile.php', function(data) {
```

---

Here is a little recap.
When using a local .json file everything works. But when i call the same file on the server it does not. 
The error i get is:

*The character encoding of the plain text document was not declared. The document will render with garbled text in some browser configurations if the document contains characters from outside the US-ASCII range. The character encoding of the file needs to be declared in the transfer protocol or file needs to use a byte order mark as an encoding signature.*

In my .php file i can get rid of this error using:
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=US-utf-8');

Even without the error in my .php both files won't work. (my database is utf8_general_ci)

Comment: Is it giving any error?

Comment: Try `echo json_encode($output,true);`

Comment: Have you tried alerting `data` or check it in the console of browser to see it what has been returned?

Comment: I found this error: The character encoding of the plain text document was not declared. Then fixed the error with header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
Now i don't have any error's but it still doesn't work. I tryed ,tru but that did nothing.

Comment: what you see when you access to http://www.example.com/jsonfile.php? are you reporting errors? try to set error_reporting(E_ALL); at top of your code to see errors or check the error log.

Comment: I think it's something with my server.  If i load a test.json local then it works. But when i got it on my server it wont.

Comment: This is the full eror code:
The character encoding of the plain text document was not declared. The document will render with garbled text in some browser configurations if the document contains characters from outside the US-ASCII range. The character encoding of the file needs to be declared in the transfer protocol or file needs to use a byte order mark as an encoding signature.

Comment: What version of PHP are you using?

Comment: PHP Version 5.3.3-7+squeeze16

Comment: Just for the sake of consistency, besides declaring the encoding, make sure both you PHP file and your JS file are encoded (saved as) UTF-8 without BOM --- I've had situations where ASCII files caused errors when dealing with UTF-8 outputs.

Answer (score 0):

A few thing you can try:

- hader('Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8', true);
- remove the Content-Type altogether
- Call mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'") after the connection to the db

Answer (score -1):

PHP white screen or no data is sign of an script error. Your ajax calls are correct, it's recomendable enable error reporting on development environment, so you need to check error logs or enable error_reporting to get the exception.

Comment: The json is working in the browser. I can't find any errors at the moment. But i will look some more :)

Comment: Could be an ajax error maybe? The database is on UTF8 too?

Comment: The database s utf8_general_ci